# Cant receive data from postMessage in react native webview

Tags: react-native

here is my injected js:

```
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
    external_url_open: null,
    height: Math.max(document.body.offsetHeight, document.body.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight)
}));

(function(){
    var attachEvent = function(elem, event, callback)
    {
        ...
    }    
    var all_links = document.querySelectorAll('a[href]');    
    if ( all_links ) {
        for ( var i in all_links ) {
            if ( all_links.hasOwnProperty(i) ) {
                attachEvent(all_links[i], 'onclick', function(e){
                    if ( new RegExp( '^https?:\/\/www.dropbox\.com.*', 'gi' ).test( this.href ) ) {
                        // handle external URL
                        e.preventDefault();
                        window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify({
                            external_url_open: this.href,
                        }));
                    }
                    
                    else { window.location.href = this.href; }
                });
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

I want to receive the pages height on react native side with this code:

```
<WebView
                ...
                javascriptEnabled={true}
                onMessage={(event) => {
                // retrieve event data
                var data = event.nativeEvent.data;  // maybe parse stringified JSON
                try {
                    data = JSON.parse(data)
                } catch ( e ) {  }
            
                // check if this message concerns us
                if ( 'object' == typeof data && data.external_url_open ) {
                    if (data.external_url_open != null){
                        // proceed with URL open request
                        Linking.openURL(data.external_url_open);
                    }
                    else {
                        height = data.height;
                        console.log(data.page_height);
                    }
                }
                }}
                injectedJavaScript={jsCode}

                ...
            />
```

the link handling part works but the height receive part doesn't and I dont see anything in console when refreshing the page. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to relocate this `else` to the outer if:

```
else {
height = data.height;
console.log(data.page_height);
}
```